# Importing row data array information into php email

Tags: php, arrays, phpmailer

I will first start by admitting I have no idea where I am going wrong with this code as I am just starting out.  I am attempting to take data from a row array and insert it into the body of an email for a notification.

This is what I have so far.

```
 $ID = $rowData['ID'];
        $Facility = $rowData['Facility'];
        $Department = $rowData['Department'];
        $Observation = $rowData['Observation'];
        $Potential = $rowData['Potential'];
        $subject = "Observation ID # - " . $rowData['ID'];
        $message = "Observation Report" . $ID . ""  . $Facility . "" . $Department . " " . $Location . "" . $Observation "";
        $from = "reports@email.com";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

I don't seem to have any problems with the code until I put the message line back in.

I am getting this error

```
(T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in your code on line 7
$message = "Observation Report" . $ID . "" . $Facility . "" . $Department . " " . $Location . "" . $Observation "";
```

What I want to do is have the email sent and have it a format like this.

```
Observation Report<br>
ID # - $ID<br>
Facility - $Facility<br>
Location - $Location<br>
```

etc...

Not sure where to go or how the code needs to be for this.  I even tried adding the \r\n in with a different format and that didn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: missing . in the last concat            $message = "Observation Report" . $ID . ""  . $Facility . "" . $Department . " " . $Location . "" . $Observation . "";

Answer (score 1):

Propably missing dot after $Observation, should be:

```
$message = "Observation Report" . $ID . ""  . $Facility . "" . $Department . " " . $Location . "" . $Observation . "";
```

But there is still something to improve, when you use " " you can just write it like that:

```
$message = "Observation Report $ID $Facility $Department $Location $Observation";
```

Comment: I feel really dumb even though missing a period or a quotation seems to be the most common error.

Comment: Just as a follow up, How would I go about separating into different lines?  Could I use the \r\n for this within the $message=....

Comment: Yes, you can use it. You can also change Content-type to text/html in header and then <br> will work (more about header in mail function you wille find here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the last dot in your message variable

```
$message = ...." . $Observation "";

$message = ..." . $Observation ."";
```